# Auto open active links in div on new tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

Been trying to automatically open active links in a div on a new tab when page is loaded

I can't edit the links to add ids or classes, it would have been much easier this way:

```
  document.getElementById('yourLinkID').click();
```

if I could add ids to the links but am not allowed to.

On the page I have

```
 <div id="boss" class="boss">
 <a href="http://example.com" title="Example.com">Example.com</a>
 <a href="http://example.com" title="Example.com">Example.com</a>
 <a href="http://example.com" title="Example.com">Example.com</a>
 <a href="http://example.com" title="Example.com">Example.com</a>
 </div>
```

This would do it in JQuery,

```
$(function(){
  $("#myDiv a").attr("target","_blank");
});
```

Any help with this in JavaScript? A working JS fiddle would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the child-nodes of you `#boss`-element. Than open each of them in a new window/tab (without using jQuery):

```js
var links = document.getElementById("boss").getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  window.open(links[i].getAttribute("href"), "_blank");
}
```

```html
<div id="boss" class="boss">
 <a href="http://example.com" title="Example.com">Example.com</a>
 <a href="http://example.com" title="Example.com">Example.com</a>
 <a href="http://example.com" title="Example.com">Example.com</a>
 <a href="http://example.com" title="Example.com">Example.com</a>
 </div>
```

Note: The code doesn't run, because SO prevents popups from being opened.

There might be a problem on running this code, if the JS is executed, before them DOM is fully loaded. You can prevent this from happending, by either wrapping the JS in a function, that you call on `<body onLoad="yourFunctionName()"` or by including the script at the very bottom of your site, right before the closing `</body>`-Tag.

EDIT:

Its not that easy to only open *unvisited* links. JavaScript does not allow to select links by "[:list](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/finding_elements_dom_using_querySelector.htm)"-selector (what would return only unvisited ones). You would need to store, what links you already opened (in a persistent file or something) and compare every list in your element with that stored list, to get unvisited links. At least, that would be my approach to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you get an error? Please check the console of you developer tools.

Comment: Its working, but i wanted only ACTIVE links (links that have not been clicked) not all links in the div, can you fix it pls?

Comment: I don't really know, what you mean. A link is active, as soon as the user clicks it. Do you want to open a clicked link in a new tab? Or open all links automatically, if the user never visited it?

Comment: I don't want visited links to open, only active ones.

Comment: Meaning, if the links have been opened before, then it shouldn't open again.

Comment: So a link becomes active, when you click it. You want a new tab instead of the page loading in current tab, when you click the link?

Comment: The page would be reloaded by me, if links have been opened to new tab before then the javascript shouldn't open those links again. It should only open none clicked links.

Comment: var links = document.getElementById("boss").getElementsByTagName("a:link");

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  window.open(links[i].getAttribute("href"), "_blank");
}

Comment: Is that possible?

Comment: Okey, thanks. But can selection be done by link color?

Comment: If link is green, open, if red don't open.

Comment: How do you change the color of the link if you can not change the classes? Where do you get those links from?

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/30y5aaLz/)

```
function setAttr(){
  var theLinks = document.getElementById("mydiv").getElementsByTagName("a");

  for(var i = 0; i < theLinks.length; i++) {
    theLinks[i].setAttribute('target','_blank');
  }
}

setAttr();
```